# Installing VirtualEnv using homebrew and pip on Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, virtualenv, pip, homebrew

When I install virtualenv using homebrew + pip I get the following warnings:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenv

    warning: no files found matching '*.egg' under directory 'virtualenv_support'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv

    warning: no files found matching '*.egg' under directory 'virtualenv_support'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing virtualenv-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

It seems like virtualenv is installed and working (virtualenv command works etc.)
What do the warnings mean though? What exactly is virtualenv_support? Should I be worried about them?

Comment: Shut down your Mac, turn around slowly and run for your life!! Seriously, when it's working, what's the problem? Usually, .egg files are used in the easy_install tools, but u used pip, so I wouldn´t care about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a warning from Python's setuptools that occurs when installing virtualenv; it'll happen when installed outside of Homebrew, too. It's not actually a problem.